# Convert an array of Objects with nested Objects into simple array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, nested-object

I have given an array of nested object and I want to convert it into a simple array of objects and I don't know how to proceed in this problem can anyone suggest me a way to solve this problem.i have tried but I haven't able to solve by myself or I haven't found anything like that

```
const data = [
  {
    attachment: {
      Name: {type: string, value: 'Amar'},
      'Second Contact': {type: 'phoneNumber', value: '+91123587900'},
      'First Contact': {type: 'phoneNumber', value: '+911234567890'},
      'Registered Office Address': {
        value: 'New Delhi',
        type: 'string',
      },
      'Company Logo': {type: 'string', value: ''},
      'Youtube ID': {type: 'string', value: ''},
    },
    creator: {
      displayName: 'xyz',
      phoneNumber: '+915453553554',
      photoURL:
        'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwixw9uJrYjnAhWOe30KHa42AFwQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fs%2Fphotos%2Fpic&psig=AOvVaw24C_LUOadGZAi3r2JtZe9b&ust=1579272070036146',
    },
  },
  {
    attachment: {
      Name: {type: string, value: 'hari'},
      'Second Contact': {type: 'phoneNumber', value: '+91153587900'},
      'First Contact': {type: 'phoneNumber', value: '+911264567890'},
      'Registered Office Address': {
        value: 'New Delhi mv',
        type: 'string',
      },
      'Company Logo': {type: 'string', value: ''},
      'Youtube ID': {type: 'string', value: ''},
    },
    creator: {
      displayName: 'xyz',
      phoneNumber: '+915453543554',
      photoURL:
        'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwixw9uJrYjnAhWOe30KHa42AFwQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fs%2Fphotos%2Fpic&psig=AOvVaw24C_LUOadGZAi3r2JtZe9b&ust=1579272070036146',
    },
  },
];
```

expected output is like this

```
[
    {
        Name:'Amar',
        'Second Contact':+91123587900,
        'First Contact':+911234567890,
        'Registered Office Address':'New Delhi',
        displayName:'xyz',
        phoneNumber:'+915453553554'   
    },
    {
        Name:'hari',
        'Second Contact':+91153587900,
        'First Contact':+911264567890,
        'Registered Office Address':'New Delhi mv',
        displayName:'xyz',
        phoneNumber:'+915453543554'     
    }
]
```

Comment: Is it only one specific case or do you want generic way to do it?

Comment: @miyavmiyav do it in a generic way

Comment: please post your solution first. what you tried to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to get few properties. you could simply use `map`. If you need a solution which works with all the properties, I will probably iterate through using `object.keys`.

I have added both solution here

```js
const data = [
  {
    "attachment": {
      "Name": {"type": "string", "value": "Amar"},
      "Second Contact": {"type": "phoneNumber", "value": "+91123587900"},
      "First Contact": {"type": "phoneNumber", "value": "+911234567890"},
      "Registered Office Address": {
        "value": "New Delhi",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Company Logo": {"type": "string", "value": ""},
      "Youtube ID": {"type": "string", "value": ""}
    },
    "creator": {
      "displayName": "xyz",
      "phoneNumber": "+915453553554",
      "photoURL":
        "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwixw9uJrYjnAhWOe30KHa42AFwQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fs%2Fphotos%2Fpic&psig=AOvVaw24C_LUOadGZAi3r2JtZe9b&ust=1579272070036146"
    }
  },
  {
    "attachment": {
      "Name": {"type": "string", "value": "hari"},
      "Second Contact": {"type": "phoneNumber", "value": "+91153587900"},
      "First Contact": {"type": "phoneNumber", "value": "+911264567890"},
      "Registered Office Address": {
        "value": "New Delhi mv",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "Company Logo": {"type": "string", "value": ""},
      "Youtube ID": {"type": "string", "value": ""}
    },
    "creator": {
      "displayName": "xyz",
      "phoneNumber": "+915453543554",
      "photoURL":
        "https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwixw9uJrYjnAhWOe30KHa42AFwQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Funsplash.com%2Fs%2Fphotos%2Fpic&psig=AOvVaw24C_LUOadGZAi3r2JtZe9b&ust=1579272070036146"
    }
  }
];

const result = data.map(item => {
  return {
    "Name": item.attachment.Name.value,
    "Second Contact": item.attachment["Second Contact"].value
  };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));


// Another generic way
const result2 = data.map(item => {
  const singleObj = {};
  Object.keys(item.attachment).forEach(key => {
singleObj[key] = item.attachment[key].value;
  });
  return singleObj;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Preety sure if you know anything about javascript it should be easy to solve. The only tricky part could be the fields with spaces like "Second Contact".

Way to solve this particular case is as follows:

```
const output = data.map(item => {
    return {
        name: item.attachment.Name.value,
        'Second Contact': item.attachment['Second Contact'].value,
        'First Contact': item.attachment['First Contact'].value,
        'Registered Office Address':item.attachment['Registered Office Address'].value,
        displayName: item.creator.displayName,
        phoneNumber: item.creator.phoneNumber 
    };
})

console.log(output);
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/chgnu1d5/